# IF EXISTS logic to create new table and/or columns

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

My goal is to make two if statements in SQL that check if a table and a column exist.

My first if statement is returning an error that says:

> the table exists with the name.

In my second statement I don't know how to check if a column is already there/not there.

First SQL statement:

```
USE [Elearn2]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[GDPR_SupportRequest]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GDPR_SupportRequest]
    (
        [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [RequestDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
        [RequestType] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [RequestQuery] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GDPR_SupportRequest] WITH CHECK 
        ADD FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
END
```

Second SQL statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserMetaData WHERE Consent != Null)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE UserMetaData 
        ADD Consent BIT NULL DEFAULT 0;
END
```

If someone could help me to fix the statement please let me know how.

Thank you

Comment: "sys.columns" is the system view that you would check for column existence.  The "object_id" value in "sys.columns" is the corresponding object_id() value of the table.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Also - you're checking **IF** they table **exists** - and if it **does exist**, you're issuing a `CREATE TABLE` statement. That doesn't make sense ..... you should check `IF NOT EXISTS ( .....)` to check to run this `CREATE TABLE` only if the table **DOES NOT** exist!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether the table `GDPR_SupportRequest` exists and creating the table if it exists, instead you should create it if the table `GDPR_SupportRequest` doesn't exists already.

```
USE [Elearn2]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[GDPR_SupportRequest]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GDPR_SupportRequest]
    (
        [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [RequestDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
        [RequestType] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [RequestQuery] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]



    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GDPR_SupportRequest] WITH CHECK 
        ADD FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
END
```

You can use the below script to check if the column `Consent` exists in the table  `UserMetaData` and if the column doesn't then you can add it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'UserMetaData'
                 AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Consent')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE UserMetaData 
        ADD Consent BIT NULL DEFAULT 0;
END
```